# Подставить заготовленному url то, что введено в input и вывести в div

Tags: javascript

Возникли трудности при изучении js, нужно сделать на чистом js такое:
Есть поле input и кнопка.
Нужно сделать так:

1. - вводим цифры и буквы (например qy123456h) в поле **input**
2. - жмем кнопку
3. - скрипт берет заранее заготовленный **url**(например
     https://site.ru/track?) и вставляет в конец то, что введено в поле
     input
4. - полученный результат https://site.ru/track?qy123456h выводится в
     блоке **div** вот так: `<div><a href="https://site.ru/track?123456">https://site.ru/track?qy123456h</a></div>`

Помогите советом или лучше примером, как это реализовать.

Comment: А с чем именно у вас проблемы? Что уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Как возникла проблема с конкатенацией двух строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо добавлять, а не менять ссылку при нажатии:

```js
add.onclick = function () {
    let val = document.getElementById('inp').value; // Получаем значение введённых данных
    let main = document.getElementsByClassName('main'); // Получаем блок родителя
    let div = document.createElement('div'); // Создаём div
    let a = document.createElement('a'); // создаём элемент a
    val = 'https://site.ru/track?' + val; // Добавляем к ссылке введённые данные
    a.innerText = val; // В текст <a> вставляем сформированную ссылку
    a.setAttribute('href', val); // Вставляем в href ссылку для кликабельности
    div.appendChild(a); // Добавляем атрибут a в div
    main[0].appendChild(div); // добавляем div в родительский блок.
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <input id="inp">
    <button id="add">Добаивть ссылку</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за решение и отдельно за комментарии к коду, они помогли мне понять как что работает)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function onClick() {
    let value = document.getElementById('input-box').value;

    let url = `https://site.ru/track/${value}`;
    
    let outputDiv =  document.getElementById('output');

    outputDiv.innerHTML = "";

    addLinkToContainer(outputDiv, url);
}

function addLinkToContainer(container, url){
    let newlink = document.createElement('a');
    newlink.setAttribute('href', url);
    newlink.innerHTML = url;
    container.appendChild(newlink);
}
```

```html
<input id="input-box" type="text" /><button onclick="onClick()">Go</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```